# 3 CSV files into a single JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have 3 csv files, loan, customer and security, each of these files are quite large (800k+ rows).  Each file is linked by a single column uniqueid.  My aim is to create a single JSON file, the code below achieves this, however, it is very slow.

My question is how can i achieve this result faster?

```
import csv
import json

def multicsvtojson():

loanscsvfile = open('C:\\***\\loan.csv', 'r')
custcsvfile = open('C:\\***\\customer.csv', 'r')
securcsvfile = open('C:\\***\\security.csv', 'r')

loansreader = csv.DictReader(loanscsvfile, delimiter=',')
custreader = csv.DictReader(custcsvfile, delimiter=',')
securreader = csv.DictReader(securcsvfile, delimiter=',')

jsonfile = open('test.json', 'w')
#ready json file

output = []
loanscount = 0
#total loan count
for loansrow in loansreader:
    loansrow['customers'] = []
    loansrow['securities'] = []

    output.append(loansrow)
    custcsvfile.seek(0)
    securcsvfile.seek(0)
    for custrow in custreader:
        if (loansrow["UniqueID"] == custrow["UniqueID"]):
            loansrow['customers'].append(custrow) 
    for securrow in securreader:
        if (loansrow["UniqueID"] == securrow["UniqueID"]):
            loansrow['securities'].append(securrow)

    loanscount = loanscount + 1 #increment the loan counter
    print(loanscount)

total = {}
total['total'] = loanscount
output.insert(0, total)

json.dump(output, jsonfile, indent=4)
```

The current output is as follow

```
[{
    "total": 2
},
{
    "uniqueID": "",
    "uniqueID2": "",
    "colA": "",
    "colB": "",
    "colC": "",
    "colD": "",
    "customers": [
        {
            "uniqueID": "",
            "custID": "",
            "colA": "",
            "colB": "",
        }
    ],
    "securities": [
        {
            "uniqueID": "",
            "secuID": "",
            "colA": "",
            "colB": ""
        }
    ]
},
{
    "uniqueID": "",
    "uniqueID2": "",
    "colA": "",
    "colB": "",
    "colC": "",
    "colD": "",
    "customers": [
        {
            "uniqueID": "",
            "custID": "",
            "colA": "",
            "colB": "",
        },
        {
            "uniqueID": "",
            "secuID": "",
            "colA": "",
            "colB": ""
        }
    ],
    "securities": [
        {
            "uniqueID": "",
            "secuID": "",
            "colA": "",
            "colB": ""
        },
        {
            "uniqueID": "",
            "secuID": "",
            "colA": "",
            "colB": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

}]

Comment: if you could sort the `custreader` and `securreader` by ID then you could break out of the for loop, decreasing your total iterations. If sorted you could keep an pointer to where you last left off to stop going through ID's that you have already gone through. you could also remove the `loanscount` as that is just getting the len() of loansreader -- saving you some time in updates.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I've figured out how to sort the customer and security files by the uniqueid.  But i',m not sure i understand how i can then break out of the loop.  
There are scenarios where a single loan will have multiple customers and/or securities would we not require a loop for this?
I've made the change for loansreader, thanks for that pointer!

Answer (score 0):

What probably costs you performance are the multiple reads of the customer and securities files. Because you reread the whole file at every loan row.

Maybe try to regroup customers and securties by ID before getting to the loans file, so you don't have to re-read every time.

```py
import csv
import json

def multicsvtojson():

    loanscsvfile = open('C:\\***\\loan.csv', 'r')
    custcsvfile = open('C:\\***\\customer.csv', 'r')
    securcsvfile = open('C:\\***\\security.csv', 'r')

    loansreader = csv.DictReader(loanscsvfile, delimiter=',')
    custreader = csv.DictReader(custcsvfile, delimiter=',')
    securreader = csv.DictReader(securcsvfile, delimiter=',')

    jsonfile = open('test.json', 'w')
    #ready json file

    output = []
    loanscount = 0

    # regroup customers by ID
    customers = {}
    for custrow in custreader:
        id = custrow["UniqueID"]
        if id not in customers:
            customers[id] = []
        customers[id].append(custrow)

    # regroup securities by ID
    securities = {}
    for securrow in securreader:
        id = securrow["UniqueID"]
        if id not in securities:
            securities[id] = []
        securities[id].append(securrow)

    #total loan count
    for loansrow in loansreader:

        loansrow['customers'] = customers.get("UniqueID", [])
        loansrow['securities'] = securities.get("UniqueID", [])
        output.append(loansrow)

        loanscount = loanscount + 1 #increment the loan counter
        print(loanscount)

    total = {}
    total['total'] = loanscount
    output.insert(0, total)

    json.dump(output, jsonfile, indent=4)
```

If the CSV files are too big to handle in memory, you can also try to use a temporary database such as [tinydb](https://pypi.org/project/tinydb/).

Comment: Thanks for that, it makes sense!
However, i'm currently getting a null value when i try and access uniqueID from the customers/securities group?  It's not picking up the column headers and i'm not quite sure why?

    for loansrow in loansreader:
        print(customers.get("uniqueId", []))

Results:
[]
[]
[]

Comment: Can you add an examples of your CSV files, with fake data and a pair of lines? That way i could try to correct if i've done something wrong.

Comment: Also, have you checked if the key names (i.e UniqueID) are OK?